# Heun's method for a ball and beam system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I have a problem with a homework request by the professor at the university but I really can't solve the equation. I have just to resolve the equation using Heun method and choosing appropriately
the discretization step (the sampling time interval), adequately motivating the choices made.
It's a ball and beam system that after a bit of steps give me these equations:

$\dot x=\begin{bmatrix} \dot x_1\\  \dot x_2\\ \dot x_3 \\ \dot x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x_2\\  x_1x_4^2-g\sin x_3\\ x_4 \\ \frac{-2mx_1x_2x_4-mgx_1\cos x_3+\tau}{mx_1^2+J}\end{bmatrix}= f(x,\tau)$

initial state condition given by the vector:

$ x_0=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

The only thing I understood is that I have to reduce that to a first grade equation imposing $ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = y$ but I don't know how to resolve then. Don't know how to proceed solving that problem with Heun method. Because I never used it and even if I see a lot of video online about it I can't resolve that problem up here. Only started using Matlab but don't know how to use it even if the prof said to us to use it if we want to resolve that. I never used finite difference methods unfortunately...

Comment: don't know how to proceed solving that problem with Heun method. Because I never used it and even if I see a lot of video online about it I can't resolve that problem up here...

Comment: @EditPiAf tell me if u need more information about the problem even if I don't have a lot more info about it.

Comment: only started using matlab but don't know how to use it even if the prof said to us to use it if we want to resolve that. I never used finite difference methods unfortunately...

Comment: @EditPiAf I modified the initial state condition thanks for the observation

Comment: Have a look at http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/ch3/heun.html

Comment: First of all ty for the help, unfortunately already checked that site and more or less I understood the way I should proceed with a "normal" first order differential equation the problem is apply that method to a more difficult one like this up here that come from a physics' problem

Comment: @Cesareo that's why I asked here because I know that here there are for sure people a lot better than me on that

Comment: Please refrain from adding things such as "PLEASE HELP ME" to the body of your question. If people wish to and are able to help, they may choose to do so, but adding unnecessary text such as that only makes it more difficult to do so and may even make some less likely to help you. If you want help, you should add more context to the question, such as what code you've tried writing, what you understand about Huen's method, etc. Doing so would actually help others reading your question know how to better help you.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  yes u right, sorry for that next time I will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the right side of your equation in Matlab format

```
  function dotx = ballbeam(t,x)
      dx2 = x(1)*x(4)^2 - g*sin(x(3));
      dx4 = (-2*m*x(1)*x(2)*x(4)-m*g*x(1)*cos(x(3))+tau)/(m*x(1)^2+J);
      dotx = [ x(2), dx2, x(4), dx4 ];
  end
```

and then feed this into a generic Heun loop

```
  function x = odeheun(f,t,x0)
      x = [x0];
      for i=1:(length(t)-1)
          h = t(i+1)-t(i);
          k1 = h*f(t(i),x(i,:));
          k2 = h*f(t(i+1),x(i,:)+k1);
          x(i+1,:) = x(i,:)+0.5*(k1+k2);
      end%for
  end%function
```

and then call it like (tested in octave)

```
  x0 = [x1_ini, 0, 0, 0 ];
  t = t0:h:tf;
  x = odeheun(@(t,x)ballbeam(t,x),t,x0); % possibly only @ballbeam in matlab
  plot(t,x(:,1));
```

Comment: ty for the answer and the time u dedicate to do this, will try that way!